# python multithread ping using pyping (with root) is returning all success,What is wrong

Tags: python-2.7, python-multithreading

Trying to develop a multi thread ping application in python using pyping library (ICMP based ping using root user).

Result is returning all success/failed as per last IP result. Codes are given below , What I am doing wrong.. (Codes Give below)

127.0.0.1 is loop back which should ping.
192.168.1.20 does not exit , which should fail.

(Please do not suggest Why I should not use root or use other method..)
Thanks ..

-------- Current Result -------------

```
# python ping_test.py 
192.168.1.20 -> 192.168.1.20 -> 0
127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1 -> 0
End of Script.
#
```

(here 0 = success , 1 = failed at end of every result)
------------- Codes -------------

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function

import threading
import sys
import time
import pyping

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,threadID ,ip):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID  = threadID
        self.ip = ip
    def run(self):
        #here do ping
        self.a = pyping.ping(self.ip)
        threadLock.acquire()        
        print(self.ip , '->' ,self.a.destination_ip , '->' , self.a.ret_code)
        threadLock.release()



#here create a thread lock
threadLock = threading.Lock()
threads = []

#collect ips 
ips = ['192.168.1.20','127.0.0.1']

i = 1
for ip in ips:
    #here create thread
    th = MyThread(i , ip)
    th.start()
    threads.append(th)
    i = i + 1


for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Comment: I too am seeing this same behavior using pmap.  Seems as though pyping in not thread safe?

Comment: I've had same issue. pyping is not threadsafe. I can suggest you to use multiprocess or use a threadsafe library.

Answer (score 0):

You may have figured this out already, but moving the threadlock up a line above the ping results in desired behavior:

```
def run(self):
    #here do ping
    threadLock.acquire()  
    self.a = pyping.ping(self.ip)      
    print(self.ip , '->' ,self.a.destination_ip , '->' , self.a.ret_code)
    threadLock.release()

('192.168.1.20', '->', '192.168.1.20', '->', 1)
('127.0.0.1', '->', '127.0.0.1', '->', 0)
('4.3.2.1', '->', '4.3.2.1', '->', 1)
('8.8.8.8', '->', '8.8.8.8', '->', 0)
('172.29.200.1', '->', '172.29.200.1', '->', 0)
('1.2.3.4', '->', '1.2.3.4', '->', 1)
```